# How to escape single quote inside jQuery variable

Tags: jquery, escaping

I have a jQuery with the following code:

```
id = 100;
name = "O'Keefe";
str = "<button type='button' onclick='selName( "+id+",\""+name+"\")'>Select</button>";
```

str is loaded into a div.

When I inspect the page it shows:

```
<button type="button" onclick="selName( 100, "O" Keefe")'>Select</button>
```

I tried escaping the single quote with

```
name = name.replace(/'/g, '\'');
```

But it didn't work.

My code works fine for names without single quote.

Any suggestions on how to deal with names with single quote?

Thanks.

Comment: HTML doesn't have any form of escaping inside attributes. So you simply can't have `'` inside an attribute if you're using `'` as the attribute value delimiter.

Comment: I tried it and everything is fine. Can you show how you are loading it into div, pls?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. After reading your comment about escaping in HTML I did a search and found a solution - replace single quotes with &#39; It worked. :)

Comment: What has this to do with jQuery? You aren't using it to create that HTML.

Comment: You can also use backtick `\``

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a string for that. Since you say you're using jQuery, you should attach the event listener with jQuery, not with inline events (which have a large number of problems, including this one - tedious quote escaping).

```
const button = $('<button>Select</button>')
  .on('click', () => selName(id, name))
  .appendTo('selectorOfWhateverYouWantToAppendThisTo');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand what you are doing, but it would require a significant change on my code. I will keep this in mind for future code. I ended up replacing the single quotes with &#39; It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
id = 100;
name = "O'Keefe";
name = name.replace(/'/g, '&#39;'); //replace single quotes
str = "<button type='button' onclick='selName("+id+",\""+name+"\")'>Select</button>";
```

When I replace the single quotes with `&#39;` the html shows:

```
<button type="button" onclick="selName( 100, "O'Keefe")">Select</button>
```

This works. Thanks.